# Running conduit through soffit into attic

Tags: electrical, roof, attic, soffit, building

I am looking to run a new circuit from one side of my house where the breaker panel is over to the other side of the house. My preference would be to run the conduit out of my garage, over approximately 30 feet, and then up to the first floor attic space. I am comfortable with all of this but I have what may be a dumb question. I would be running the conduit into the soffit in order to then pull into the attic. The attic is sealed tight with spray foam insulation. How do I carefully remove part of the soffit in order to access and drill any holes necessary to pull the conduit (and wiring) into the attic?  I took a picture of another conduit that is already running.  Unfortunately, this isn't large enough to add the additional wiring.

Also, if I were do this by running conduit along the outside of the house, is there a conduit that does not need to be buried?

[image]

Comment: What kind of conduit are you looking at that _needs_ to be buried? Schedule 40 or 80 PVC and metal conduit can both be left exposed (exactly like the piece in your picture). Most people _want_ to bury it (underground or in a wall) to hide it so it's not visible, it's not a requirement of installation.

Comment: Thank you.  I am hopeful that I can run it up into the attic instead of all outside but good to know that it does not need to be buried.  Now to figure out how to get beyond the soffit.

Comment: Why do you want to go out side? I would make a hole in the wall on the inside then drill up through the plate, using Romex inside the wall and through the attic. Much easier and cheaper than conduit.

Comment: What is this circuit powering?

Comment: The circuit will be powering a pool heater.  The breaker box is in my garage with no attic space above nor basement below.  The line needs to run to the opposite side of the house.  If I come out of the garage and go approximately 30 ft, I can run conduit up through the soffit to access a first floor attic.  This will allow me to switch to romex to run across the attic and then switch back to run out and down the other side of the house.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I did discover, however, how to get one of the soffit panels loose to hopefully run to the attic.